# How to set "None" or "Implicit" authentication type for my custom connector?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

We are trying to build a custom connector to a data source. We need not want authentication for now. If we set "Implicit" it gives as below image

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLsOs.png)

If we set it as "None" the builder ".mez" file doesn't even load. It is showing some compilation errors while building itself.

How to set up authentication for custom connectors with minimal effort or even avoid authentication?

///Below is our code///

```
[DataSource.Kind="PQExtension1", Publish="PQExtension1.Publish"]
shared PQExtension1.Contents = () as table =>
let
// Read the JSON file
jsonData = Json.Document(File.Contents(filePath)),

// Extract the cube values
cube = jsonData[cube],

// Extract the dimension values
dimension = jsonData[dimension],

// Convert dimension values to a table
dimensionTable = Table.FromColumns(Record.FieldValues(dimension), Record.FieldNames(dimension)),

// Expand the cube values
cubeTable = Table.FromList(cube, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

// Create a new column for each dimension
finalTable = Table.AddColumn(cubeTable, "Dimensions", each dimensionTable)
in
finalTable;

// Data Source Kind description
PQExtension1 = [
Authentication = [
// Key = [],
// UsernamePassword = [],
// Windows = [],
Implicit = []
],
Label = Extension.LoadString("DataSourceLabel")
];

// Data Source UI publishing description
PQExtension1.Publish = [
Beta = true,
Category = "Other",
ButtonText = { Extension.LoadString("ButtonTitle"), Extension.LoadString("ButtonHelp") },
LearnMoreUrl = "https://powerbi.microsoft.com/",
SourceImage = PQExtension1.Icons,
SourceTypeImage = PQExtension1.Icons
];

PQExtension1.Icons = [
Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("PQExtension116.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension120.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension124.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension132.png") },
Icon32 = { Extension.Contents("PQExtension132.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension140.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension148.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension164.png") }
];
```

Custom Connector Without authentication